# expanding section on a HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

There's this website http://www.phpvideotutorials.com/  I basically wanted to get some insights on how each right and left columns expands dynamically when these respective columns are clicked and contracts from expanded state when clicked again. 
I'm new to web development, at least dynamic website development using jQuery and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [the source code](http://www.phpvideotutorials.com/js/phpvt.js).  The (simplified) operative part is here:

```
var dm = $('#developermonkey');
dm.bind('click', function(e) {
    dm.animate({'right' : 400 });
});
```

So it's binding a click event to a function, which animates the element's *right* CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

It's done with a javascript library called jQuery http://jquery.com you can read more about it there and see examples of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

This can be found from view source. Please refer this code,

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">text
<a id="lefta">click</a>
</div>
```

`JavaScript` ​

```
 $('#lefta').bind('click', function(e) {
    $('#left').css({'width' : 200 }); 
    $('#left').animate({'left' : 150 }, 400);
 });
​
```

Here in example I am increasing width of div also so as to explain you how jQuery css function works so that you can use to set additional css style while moving your div. Please refer following fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/TqCmB/